# how many solutions to non-linear simultaneous equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

I'm doing a Lagrange multiplier optimization problem, and I wound up with the following simultaneous equations:

$2x + 1 -2\lambda x = 0$
$4y-2 \lambda y = 0$
$6z-2 \lambda z = 0$
$-x^2 - y^2 - z^2 + 1 = 0$

I am asked to find ALL solutions, and I managed to find 2 solutions (had to assume that y and z were both zero so equation 2 and 3 would make sense) :

$\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{2}, x_1 = -1$
$\lambda_2 = \frac{3}{2}, x_2 = 1$

But how do I know that these two are ALL the solutions? Is there any way to tell how many solutions I should be able to get, or maybe suggest how to get more solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you concluding that both $y$ and $z$ must be zero? At least one must vanish, but both together need not.

Comment: I didn't say that was ALWAYS the case, just one case I found to be solvable...This is why I brought up my original question: How do I know when to stop messing with these equations/ when have I found them all?

Comment: You should pretty much try every option you can: If you have $ab=0$, then you must consider $a=0$ and $b=0$ as separate cases. Which means that if you've got $n$ equations like that, you'll end up with $2^n$ cases to consider. (You've got $n=2$ here, so it's not too bad.)

Comment: Okay, that helps out. I did what you said took turns making only = 0 and only z = 0 and got a total of 6 solutions. Hopefully that completes the list of solutions.

Comment: That seems correct. I'd suggest submitting your work as an answer to your own question. That way, you can get some rep, we can give you feedback, and anyone who has similar issues may make use of it in the future.

Comment: As a supplement to that last comment: ["Can I answer my own question?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Since the 2nd and 3rd equation are contradictory when both y and z are not zero, I must try several scenarios where just y, just z, and both y and z are equal to 0. For the y=z=0 case:

Solve equation 1 for x:
$x = \frac{-1}{2-2\lambda}$

plug into equation 4, solve for lambda:

$\lambda = \frac{8 \pm \sqrt{64-48}}{8}$

For each of these two answers, plug back into the x equation for 2 solutions:

$
 x_1 = -1, 
 y_1 = 0, 
 z_1 = 0, 
 \lambda_1 = \frac{1}{2}$

$
 x_2 = 1 ,
 y_2 = 0 ,
 z_2 = 0 ,
 \lambda_2 = \frac{3}{2}
$

Now take the case where z = 0,

Solve equation 2 for lambda:

$\lambda = 2$

Into equation 1:

$x = \frac{1}{2}$

both of these into equation 4:

$y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}$

Giving two more solutions of:

$x_3 = \frac{1}{2}, y_3 = \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}, z_3 = 0, \lambda_3 = 2$
$x_4 = \frac{1}{2}, y_4 = -\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}, z_4 = 0, \lambda_4 = 2$

Taking the case where y = 0:

Solve equation 3 for lambda:

$\lambda = 3$

Into equation 1:

$x = \frac{1}{4}$

both into equation 4:

$z = \pm \sqrt{\frac{15}{16}}$

Giving the final two solutions of:

$x_5 = \frac{1}{4}, y_5 = 0, z_5 = \sqrt{\frac{15}{16}}, \lambda_5 = 3$
$x_6 = \frac{1}{4}, y_6 = 0, z_6 = -\sqrt{\frac{15}{16}}, \lambda_6 = 3$

I can't think of any other possibility that would be mathematically legal. If I assume x=0, the first equation becomes $1=0$ which can't happen. Similarly, if I assume lambda = 0, then the 4th equation will eventually become impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat different way to organize solving the equations. Observe that the three equations may be expressed as

$$2x(\lambda-1)=1,\quad 2y(\lambda-2)=0,\quad 2z(\lambda-3)=0.$$ The last two equations imply three cases:

- $\boxed{\lambda\neq 2,3}\quad$ We require $y=z=0$, and then the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ yields $\hspace{2.25cm}$ $x=\pm 1$. The first equation then gives $\lambda=1\mp\frac12=\frac12,\frac32$.
- $\boxed{\lambda=2}\quad$ Solving the first and third equations yields $(x,z)=
  (\frac12,0)$. The constraint then $\hspace{1.8cm}$ gives $y=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.
- $\boxed{\lambda=3}\quad$ Solving the first and second equations yields $(x,y)=
  (\frac14,0)$. The constraint then $\hspace{1.8cm}$ gives $z=\pm \frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}$.

This gives a total of six solutions. As a check, the objective function for this problem is $F(x)=x^2+x+2y^2+3z^2=(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+2y^2+3z^2$ i.e. level sets of ellipses centered at $(-\frac12,0,0)$. It's worth visualizing that to confirm that six solutions are the expected number.